# ModPow not calculating fast enough c#

Tags: c#, math, biginteger

Hi I am trying to do a `ModPow` calculation as fast as possible, the calculation is as such **P^e%n**. Test data is 888999000^202404606%237291793913, **I am aware of the BigInteger.ModPow(P, e, n)** however I am not supposed to use this function so I have written the following function which is relatively slow, and I really need to speed up the process. (I am sure that maybe if I split the calculation numbers in half and turn it into two individual calculations it will speed up the process hopefully), anyway heres what I've written so far.

```
private static BigInteger ModPow(BigInteger baseNum, BigInteger exponent, BigInteger modulus)
{
    BigInteger c;
    if (modulus == 1)
        return 0;
    c = 1;
    for (BigInteger e_prime = 1; e_prime <= exponent; e_prime++)
    {
        c = (c * baseNum) % modulus;
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: This will not do anything, it is the same as just returning c * baseBum % modulus

Comment: What will do it then?

Comment: Have you seen [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097459/alternative-to-biginteger-modpow-in-c-sharp) ?

Comment: that for loop isn't doing anything really, if you delete the whole body of this method and just put "return baseNum % modulus" it will have the same result, and this surely is not what you intend to do

Comment: @EduG, I don't think that you are right. To me it seems that the `for` loop does what is intended to do: i.e. applies multiplication by `baseNum` and modulo `modulus` exactly `exponent` times. Why do you think result would be the same without it? For example `(c * baseNum) % modulus` and `(((c * baseNum) % modulus) * baseNum)  % modulus` are generally different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is probably [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Further_applications) which works for modulo power as well. The code should be something like this:

```
private static BigInteger ModPow(BigInteger baseNum, BigInteger exponent, BigInteger modulus)
{
    BigInteger pow = 1;
    if (modulus == 1)
        return 0;
    BigInteger curPow = baseNum % modulus;
    BigInteger res = 1;
    while(exponent > 0){
        if (exponent % 2 == 1)
            res = (res * curPow) % modulus;
        exponent = exponent / 2;
        curPow = (curPow * curPow) % modulus;  // square curPow
    }
    return res;
}
```

This method performance is `O(log(exponent))` rather than `O(exponent)` for your code in term of number of multiplications and modulo operations (that are probably not `O(1)` for `BigInteger` but details depend on implementation). Also note that the code above should not be used for any real world crypto-related implementations because it introduces vulnerability (performance depends on actual value of the `exponent`, particularly how many `1` bits there are there (see [Timing attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timing_attack) for some details).

Answer (score 1):

## Well, try this

```
private static BigInteger ModPow(BigInteger baseNum, BigInteger exponent, BigInteger modulus)
{
       BigInteger B, D;
       B = baseNum;

       B %= modulus;
       D = 1;
       if ((exponent & 1) == 1)
       {
           D = B;
       }

        while (exponent > 1)
        {
             exponent >>= 1;
             B = (B * B) % modulus;
             if ((exponent & 1) == 1)
             {
                 D = (D * B) % modulus;
             }
         }
         return (BigInteger)D;
}
```